How can I set up right frame?(array issue)
I want to analyze audio file for my final graduate project.
I chose to use pyaudioanalysis as tool.
I have trouble to set up frame & hop...
import numpy as np
from pyAudioAnalysis import audioBasicIO
from pyAudioAnalysis import ShortTermFeatures

[Fs, x] = audioBasicIO.read_audio_file("/content/drive/MyDrive/audio.wav")


print("Sample rate (Fs):", Fs)
print("Total samples (x):", len(x))


frame_size = 0.1 * Fs
hop_size = 0.05 * Fs

print("Frame size:", frame_size)
print("Hop size:", hop_size)


try:
    [F, F_names] = ShortTermFeatures.feature_extraction(x, Fs, frame_size, hop_size)
    print("Feature extraction successful")
except ValueError as e:
    print("Error in feature extraction:", e)

=====================================================================
Sample rate (Fs): 48000
Total samples (x): 478080
Frame size: 4800.0
Hop size: 2400.0
Error in feature extraction: cannot reshape array of size 9600 into shape (480,10)

Sample rate (Fs): 48000
Total samples (x): 478080
Frame size: 4800.0
Hop size: 2400.0
Error in feature extraction: cannot reshape array of size 9600 into shape (480,10)


Why do you think you can reshape 9600 elements into 480x10 elements?  9600 is 4800 x 2, so is there a stereo/mono mismatch?  Or perhaps a bytes-per-sample problem?

i am a beginner. so i couldn't understand abount reshape...
I got some advices from GPT, but they couldn't solve this problem
